# Check if ActiveWindow is a certaion dialog

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm trying to to decide if my active window is a dialog of a certain kind and then send it a message. This code works, but causes an assertion and i think the reason it is working is that the check returns none zero error code.

Code snippet:

```
 CWnd* pWnd = AfxGetMainWnd( )->GetActiveWindow( );

   if( pWnd->IsKindOf( RUNTIME_CLASS( CMyialog ) ) )
   {
    pWnd->SendMessage( UM_MY_MESSAGE, 0, 0 );
   }
```

CMyDialog has the macro `DECLARE_SERIAL` and `IMPLEMENT_SERIAL` and also i am sure that this is the active window at this time, however i still need to assure it is that programmatically.

Comment: pWnd may be NULL! Please tell us where you get the ASSERT.

Comment: Shame on me. That was exactly what was happening.I'll be deleting this question soon.